# Javascript prompt box field size limit

Tags: javascript, html

`3363` is the `size of my string` that will be displayed but the `limit of chars` it can `show` is `2000.`

Is there anyway around this superficial limit?

```
  window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl + C" ,   
                 document.getElementById("codeArea").value);
```

How can I make a dialog that lets me set the size limit for the field? Thanks

Comment: Generally I would avoid the usage of `promp` and `alert` at least I would only use it as fallback.  The problem is that depending how the browser or the system implements it, it would block the whole window it belongs to with its tabs, which could be really annoying. If I then want to access the other tabs, I would need to react on the dialog even if I would not like to at the moment.

Comment: @R00059159 Did you find any answer useful? If not please comment. If yes mark as answered please.

Answer (score 1):

This is implementation dependent and not in the spec. So every browser has a different limit here i suppose. And no, there is no way to change that. 
It is bad UI anyway to do it so big.
 Make a dialog in html instead. Even a modal one if needed.

Answer (score 1):

AS far as windows.prompt is concerned it is not possible to change config parameter such as size.

Either you can write your own prompt box or you can use jquery dialog like this http://jqueryui.com/dialog/